# How is it possible to trust a public key that can confirm a message's signature?

Tags: public-key

Let's assume I am able to confirm a certain message's signature with a public key that seems to be from Alice.
So I should be sure that the sender of that message is really Alice. But what if I have a public key where I think it is from Alice but actually is not and it still can confirms the signature of the message I got. So I am thinking it is from Alice since I used a key that is published as Alice's Public Key just from somebody else and that can confirm a message's signature I got where I think it is from Alice.

How can I be sure that both the message and the public key are really from the person they are named to be from?

There might be some weird thinking mistake I did here so I'd be happy to get enlightened.

Tried to visualize it.

[image: Public Key Usage]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to _know_ whose public key it is. This is the point PKI (public key infrastructures) is trying to solve.

Comment: So I have to know the owner in person and probably it is best to exchange the public key like physically with a USB-stick or how is it supposed to work without corruption?

Comment: A public key is not used to decipher. It can verify a signature, which attests that a signed message was signed by the party holding the corresponding private key. A third party can attest that this key really belongs to Alice. That's what happens when you or your browser trust that this page comes from stackexchange.com

Comment: So if the public key is not meant to be used for deciphering it is meant to be used for encrypting a message that only the party holding the respective private key can decipher this message, right?

Comment: @quizmaster987: yes that's one possible use of a public key. But encryption is not the only use of public key, or even the most common. The most ubiquitous use of a public key is verifying a [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) made with the corresponding private key.

Comment: @fgrieu Thank you, the illustration on the linked page is useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not commenting for what purpose your are going to use public key and answer your main question:

> How is it possible to trust a public key ...?

This one of the most important questions in cryptography: key distribution. Here are some possible solutions:

- You can for instance meet Alice and exchange keys personally (but it is applicable in rare real cases).
- Or you can use some channel that you trust to exchange keys.
- Or you use PKI. Namely some certification authority issues a certificate confirming that the public key belongs to a particular person. The advantage is, that you can exchange certificates also via insecure channel. But to use PKI you need of course trust particular certification authority.

Comment: Another common way to get trust about Alice's public key that was obtained thru an un-trusted channel (such a plain email) is to check a digest/fingerprint/hash of that public key over a communication channel that we trust for integrity and origin, like over the phone where we believe that we can recognize Alice's voice, or better from a business card we got from Alice in person. PGP/OpenPGP/GPG has provisions for that, and there in a non-zero percentage of business cards with an OpenPGP key fingerprint; [example](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B71ST9IIMAAy-Xg.jpg)

Comment: There is also PGP's web of trust model (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61360/what-is-the-web-of-trust), which aims to enable you to verify that the public key purported to belong to Alice does in fact belong to Alice - without you having to verify this by communicating directly with Alice through some out-of-band method, and in a decentralized way that does not involve CA's.

Comment: @fgrieu: Yes, good point.

Comment: Symmetric key cryptography supposes a secure channel. In fact, you can see it as an extension (on time) of that trusted channel. PKI is for an untrusted channel.

Comment: @McFly: The question is about PKI. I don't understand why are you talking about symmetric key cryptography.

Comment: @mentallurg, well... when you say (1) *You can for instance meet Alice and exchange keys personally;* (2) *Or you can use some channel that you trust to exchange keys.*. By using a public-key cryptosystem, (1) and (2) are everything people do not want, but only by using a symmetric one.

Comment: @McFly: If there are only 2 people involved, then you are right, PKI is not necessary, symmetric is sufficient. But if there are more than 2 people involved, it is hard to implement signature without PKI.

Comment: @mental, maybe I was not clear: I didn't say that "PKI is not necessary". PKI is very necessary; it is essential for many two-party settings: client-browser and an internet-banking server. My point is: public-key cryptography supposes an untrusted channel. It came to allows us to do cryptography out of the supposition of a trusted channel.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a more sophisticated threat is the one in the so-called [identity misbind attack](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.1051).

To summarize it, let's consider that Alice didn't register her public key in a CA --- Certification Authority and that she has used these keys to run protocols. Now, let's suppose that a Mr. X can ask a CA to register a digital certification of the Alices' public-key, whose private-key he doesn't know (maybe in a specific context the CA doesn't ask for a 'proof of ownership' of the private key, as more secure CA do).

This can be a source of a lot of problems; see this [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-45146-4_24.pdf). So to answering your question: you must trust a PKI.